# How to select all the text in a editText with adb?

Tags: android, adb, android-edittext

Is it possible to select all the text in an `editText` with ADB in android?
Right now, I'm using the command:

```
sudo /Applications/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_DEL
```

50 times, so that it erases the whole sentence, but it is very slow.

Comment: Using ScrCpy, I can see I can use CTRL+A somehow. Maybe possible to trigger this instead?

Answer (score 2):

try long press on the textedit with adb swipe

```
adb shell input swipe 100 200 100 200 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Throw the following command on an active text box

**start /B adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_MENU & adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_A
perl -e 'select(undef,undef,undef,.3)' & adb shell input keyevent KEYCODE_BACK**

The second line removes the activated menu from your app if it has one. If it does not, run only the first line.

Comment: What is happening? Any error? Please give us more details so I can look.